# Can an infinite sequence of integers generate integer-area triangles?

Tags: sequences-and-series, nt.number-theory

(asked by Shanzhen Gao, shanzhengao at yahoo.com, on the Q&A board at JMM)

Does there exist an infinite, monotonically increasing sequence of integers $\{ a_n \}_{n \geq 0}$ such that for any $n$, the three integers $(a_n, a_{n+1}, a_{n+2})$ are the side lengths of a plane triangle with integer area?

Comment: uhm, 345345345... ? We probably need unbounded or something.

Comment: The question has been edited and fixed to reflect the original intent of the problem. 

Comment: This is unlikely, but it could happen that such a sequence exists which is unbounded but essentially non-monotonic (i.e. it remains non-monotonic even after finitely many terms are omitted).

Comment: Agree with Qiaochu: no obvious reason why it has to be increasing. 

Comment: I can't answer this question. I think I'd have more chance if I were allowed to use rational numbers rather than integers. My computer says "5863, 14820, 19825, 29575, 32500, 51675, 54575". 

Comment: If you have a solution in rational numbers, and they denominators do not increase without bound, then you could multiply the whole list by the lcm of the possible denominators.  Not likely, just saying...

Answer (score 4):

I'll throw out a dumb idea: can anyone find a rational point on

$$y^2 = - (x^2-x+1)(x^2+x+1)(x^2-x-1)(x^2+x-1)?$$

UPDATE: The above formula used to have a sign error, which I have just fixed, and Bjorn's reponse was to the version with the sign error. Thanks to Kevin Buzzard for pointing this out to me.

Because, if so, $a_n=x^n$ gives triangles with rational area. Of course, this still wouldn't give an integer solution, but it would rule out a number of easy arguments against one existing.

I did a brute force search of values of $x$ with numerator and denominator under 5000 and didn't find any, but I don't think that is large enough to even count as evidence against one existing.

Comment: apart from (0,1), I guess

Comment: There are no rational points other than $(0,\pm 1)$.  Your curve has the form $y^2=f(x^2)$.  So it maps to the genus 1 curve $y^2=f(x)$, whose smooth projective model has 4 obvious rational points (above $x=0$ and $x=\infty$).  There are no others since Magma says that its Jacobian (which is the same curve) has rank 0 and torsion subgroup of size 4.

Comment: Hold your horses everyone. Hasn't David made a sign error? y^2=-RHS is the relevant equation, right? @David: I don't think this will pan out, even with the sign fix. However trying something with small period bigger than 1 is probably worth doing.

Comment: Update: David fixed the sign error. Thanks David. So now Bjorn's comments don't apply because unfortunately the genus 1 curve y^2=f(x) has (for me at least) no obvious rational points at all. There are standard ways of analysing this curve but we have to wait until someone applies them. First thing to do is perhaps to check for no p-adic points for primes p of bad reduction.

Comment: The corrected curve has no $2$-adic points.  In fact, even the genus 1 curve it maps to has no $2$-adic points.  Proof: The quartic is $-1$ mod 4 whenever $x$ is in $\mathbb{Z}_2$.  Because of the $x \mapsto 1/x$ symmetry, there aren't any points with $x \in \mathbb{Q}_2$ either.

Answer (score 2):

To find this sequence, if it exists, you would need to find a set of [Heronian triangles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heronian_triangle) such that the lengths of sides a:b:c in each triangle corresponded to sides b:c:d in the next.  The series of triangle proportions could (and likely will, if it exsts, I think) contain a cycle wherein a multiplier is introduced after each cycle, such that the triangles after x:y:z are y:z:(a*n), z:(a*n):(b*n), and (a*n):(b*n):(c*n).

A cursory search of the hundred smallest integer Heronian triangles yields no such set longer than 2 triangles, and no such cycle.  As Heronian triangles can be parametrically enumerated, it would be possible to perform a brute force search of a sizable number of them for such a sequence or cycle.

Comment: It's not clear to me why such a sequence would have to have that sort of periodicity.

Comment: I don't see why either. On the other hand, this is a plausible way that one could construct such a sequence, so it is worth recording that it doesn't work.

Comment: updating to reflect the possibility of lack of periodicity

Comment: Also, to clarify, while periodicity is not a requirement, I think a periodic solution is far more likely, as it would require a smaller number of non-congruent triangles to be found.